# NoMethodError in Discussions#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below is code extract from my file `Users/JBossman/sites/discussions/app/views/discussions/_form.html.erb` where line #20 raised this error `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`

```
enter code here
<%= simple_form_for(@discussion) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.input :title, required: true, input_html: { class: 'input' }, wrapper: false, label_html: { class: "label" } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.input :content, required: true, input_html: { class: 'textarea' }, wrapper: false, label_html: { class: "label" } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Channel</label>
    <div class="control has-icons-left">
      <span class="select">
        <%= f.input_field :channel_id, collection:@channels.map { |c| [c.channel, c.id] }, prompt: "Select channel" %>
      </span>
      <span class="icon is-small is-left">
        <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.button :submit, class:"button is-info" %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You have not defined instance variable `@channels` from action so here you are getting `nil` on which `map` method is called which threw error.

Comment: yeah i forgot to add it up in my params hence was getting nil.

Answer (score 0):

the error is here: `@channels.map { |c| [c.channel, c.id] }`

your `@channels` variable is `nil`.
make sure you set `@channels` in your create action.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@channels` is `nil`. Ideally, it should be initialized as `[]` empty array.

Alternatively, you can also use `(@channels || []).map { |c| [c.channel, c.id] }` to render empty form.

Answer (score 0):

change `@channels.map { |c| [c.channel, c.id] }` to below, as `@channels` is not set(nil).

Assuming that you are having `Channel` model.

i. If you want to display all the channels in collection, then you can do it as below:

`Channel.pluck(:channel, :id)`

ii. If you want to display specific channels in collection, then define `scope` in `Channel` like `favorites`

`Channel.favorites.pluck(:channel, :id)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem with a little change .map to .collect function, you may give it a try..

Comment: Aren't `map` and `collect` just aliases of each other?